# Cell color not working

Tags: colortbl, texlive-2019

For some reason, I can't render colored cell with `\cellcolor` anymore. MWE below. It worked in TL 2018, but I can't get it to work in TL 2019.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\colorlet{lightgrey}{lightgray}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {X[,c,]X[,c,]X[,c,]X[,c,]X[,c,]X[,c,]X[,c,]X[,c,]}
7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} JTD} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{ISC2} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} $-$} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} JTRF} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} WDRF} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} BORF} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} EXTRF} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} PORF} \\ \hline
R/W & R/W & R & R/W & R/W & R/W & R/W & R/W \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{tabu}
\caption{Position of the ISC2 bit in the MCUCSR register.}
\label{fig:intmcucsr}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tabu` is broken, use `tabularx` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\colorlet{lightgrey}{lightgray}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{YYYYYYYY}
7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} JTD} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{ISC2} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} $-$} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} JTRF} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} WDRF} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} BORF} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} EXTRF} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{lightgrey} PORF} \\ \hline
R/W & R/W & R & R/W & R/W & R/W & R/W & R/W \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Position of the ISC2 bit in the MCUCSR register.}
\label{fig:intmcucsr}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use `\rowcolor{lightgrey}` and a single `\cellcolor{white}`?

Comment: @Bernard I don't like to make too many changes in the original code, just enough to make things work, the OP should still have the feeling that it is his or her code.

Comment: @MisoSoup I fully agree with you, but it is still possible to suggests improvements in the code, and explain what you suggest and why. For example by issue two MWEs (one with modified original code, one with your suggested improvements).